# Trying new columns from subgroups of grouped data in pandas, loc function problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write new columns from subgroups(service_id) of 'data' and get the 'count' values.

My data:

```
count | service_id | date  
  2  ------------        8  -------     15-11  
  5  ------------        2    -------   15-11  
  4         ------------ 5 -------      15-11  
  3        ------------  3    -------   16-11  
  2         ------------ 8   -------    16-11  
  1    ------------      2     -------  17-11
```

Desired Output:

```
--date--|---2---|---3---|---5---|---8-  ##new headers are the subgroups 'service_id'  
-15-11----5---------------4-------2  
-16-11-------------3---------------2  
-17-11----1-------------------------
```

Sorry, I have no idea how to write a table here.

I have tried:

- List all unique service_id's to a variable. a = ['2','3','5,'8']
- List all unique date to a variable. b = ['15-11','16-11','17-11']

Then a couple of for loops and if's.

```
for num, row in df7.iterrows():
    for elem in b:
        if row['date'] == elem:
            aux1 = str(elem)
            df9.loc[num].data = aux1
            for memb in a:
                if row['service_id'] == memb:
                    aux = str(memb)
                    df9.loc[num].aux = row['count']
```

I have found some errors with this code, I don't think I have understood  how to use loc funcion.

this is the output error:

> KeyError: 'the label [0] is not in the [index]'

But any other solution is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried like this to get the desired output.

```
grouped = df.groupby('service_id')
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
​
for g, n in grouped:
    g_i = grouped.get_group(g)
    date_ = g_i.date

    for i, e in enumerate(date_):
        new_df.loc[e, 'date'] = e
        new_df.loc[e, g] = list(g_i.count1)[i]
​
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (new_df)

    date    2    3    5    8
0  15-11  5.0  NaN  4.0  2.0
1  17-11  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  16-11  NaN  3.0  NaN  2.0
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! Actualy I cant compile your code, it says: "TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable "to this line: new_df.loc[e, g] = list(g_i.count)[i]. BUT you taught me how to use loc!! I have fixed it, using loc[index,value] and then a groupby[date]. Now it is perfect, thank you so much!